# Splitting up OOP components and passing data between them

Tags: php, oop

*An admin decides to ban some users and gets their IDs. What would be the best way to write it in a flexible and OOP manner?*

The suggestions were made without the use of data mappers in mind as I don't see myself using such an approach yet, however if deemed necessary I would highly appreciate some good examples on how to use in such a situation as I have found online examples to be lacking.

*Here's what I've thought of this far:*

1. A `User` object which is made from a database table such as 'Users'. This object should:

   **a)** Have methods to fetch a row and set variables from the data stored?

   **b)** Have the ban state stored in the same database row as username, password and email etc.?

   **c)** Have the ban state map itself to a variable such as `public $banned;`?
2. A `UserControl` object which is made for handling functionality such as banning.

   **a)** Should this object be passed a `User` object and grab it's ID, or just the ID as a parameter?

   **b)** Should a new `UserControl` object be created per user it needs to ban or be static?

   **c)** Should this object simply toggle the `$banned` and have the `User` object save itself afterwards, or do the logic itself; set the 'banned' column in the Users table on the row where the given ID is?

I figured that if I put all these methods into the `User` object it would soon become a God object with `$user->hasImages();`, `$user->isBanned();` and `$user->sendNewsFeed();`, so I could need some advice on how to do this in a manner that would be flexible enough to add and remove functionality easily in an environment where a large number of users is handled and the use of collections and such is used.

Answer (score 2):

Id recommend an ACL implementation. Its more than youre asking about currently but i have a hard time believing you wont need to manage access at varying levels (admin, guest, user, etc.) to varying things (forums, images, pages, etc.). By using an ACL you could use the same code for everything and a "ban" would simply be an ACL which denies access to everything.

You can take a look at the [`Zend_Acl`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html) component for reference but whether you need something that robust or not is your decision.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a UserStatus field in the User object and represent Banned, Guest, User, Mod, Admin, whatever in that object then just see if their status is Banned.